# Adding classes to filtered items and hidden items in Isotope. Buttons not checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, jquery-isotope

I know this question has been answered, and [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nY9V/169/) which achieves exactly what I want to do, HOWEVER, in the example they use radio buttons, whereas I'm using a set of buttons (essentially just divs which gain a class of .active once clicked).

I've tried to adapt the code so 'filters' gives the same output as it does on the example, and as far as I can tell it does (An array with the name of the filter class inside), so I can't tell why it isn't working.

Here is my edited code...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var $container = $('#content');

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.box',
    });

    $('.nav a').click(function(){

        $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');

      $items = $('.box'); // to reference methods on all .item divs later
        // alert($items.length);

        // get checked checkboxes values
        var filters = [];

          filters.push(selector);
          console.log(filters);

         $container.isotope({
                filter: filters
            }, function($changedItems, instance) {
                instance.$allAtoms.filter('.isotope-hidden').removeClass('is-filtered');
                alert((instance.$allAtoms.filter('.isotope-hidden')).length); // here it is
                instance.$filteredAtoms.addClass('is-filtered');
            });

      return false;

    });

    });
```

Any ideas as to why my version doesn't work would be appreciated.

Here is a link to my [NOT WORKING EXAMPLE](http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/FN10015/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `filters` is an array. I think it should be a string to work.

So just do that:

```
var filters = [];
filters.push(selector);
filters = filters.join(', ');
```

In fact, if you'll only use one filter at a time (as it appears), you can use your variable `selector` directly, as it already contains your filter class name.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I did actually have it like that at one point. The isotope now works but I'm back to my main problem. It doesnt add the 'is-filtered' class like it should do. It adds the .isotope-hidden class but seems to stop functioning before the alert, which doesn't work either

Comment: I wasn't able to find this callback function in isotope's docs. So it's hard to know why it isn't firing. Have you tried to update the version of the plugin to the same as the working fiddle?

Comment: That was it! I can't believe it. I'd thought about checking but shrugged it off as unlikely, what a plum! Thanks

Comment: I've spent some time searching it, and the version was the only explanation I could think. Glad that helped!